# Html image crop + showing image code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am developing an Cordova mobile App.
I want to add profile pictures, so i have to add a croping tool.

I created an example

```js
function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#vorschau').attr('src', e.target.result);
      $('#bild_code').html(e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

$('#box').draggable({
  containment: '#main'
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#bild_code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <div id="main">
    <img id="vorschau" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="bild_code"></div>
</div>
```

Thats my basic idea. When you chose an image you see the code, which i want to upload later, but thats not the problem.
When you are moving the black box and then for example click on a button that code should change, so that i am able to upload the croped-image-code.
Is there an easy solution?

Hope you can help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works. I added a 100x100 (same size as the box) hidden canvas to the page. When you drag the box I take the top and left of the box and use `context.drawImage` using the box's position and using an area of 100x100, which crops the image where the box is and draws it inside the hidden canvas. Then I get the cropped image's source from the canvas using `toDataUrl()`

```js
function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#vorschau').attr('src', e.target.result);
      $('#bild_code').html(e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

$('#box').draggable({
  containment: '#main'
  ,drag: function() {
    crop();
  },
});

function crop(){
    var crop_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var left = $('#box').position().left;
    var top = $('#box').position().top;

    crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage($('#vorschau')[0], left, top, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    $('#bild_code').html(crop_canvas.toDataURL());
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#bild_code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <div id="main">
    <img id="vorschau" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="bild_code"></div>
</div>

<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100" style="display:none;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/RubaXa/jquery.fileapi/. Even though the plugin itself is no longer updated, it's underlying piece of code (https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/) is.

The examples "userpic + crop" [here](http://rubaxa.github.io/jquery.fileapi/) seem to be exactly what you requested.