# Javascript image Crop canvas bug

Tags: javascript, android, canvas

I am trying to make an image picker where you can select an area on the picture and than upload it to a server.
Now i have copied some things out of my code, the problem is that it is not working like it should do.
In my last questions someone gave me a perfect tip how to crop, which I have used and already integrated in my code. Last post: [Html image crop + showing image code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294285/html-image-crop-showing-image-code/35294842#35294842)

The Problem is that when i click on 'OK' the image is not croped right. The demensions are not right and the position, which you can select is also wrong:

```js
function readURL(input) { //Seite6

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
   document.getElementById("seite6_bb").style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("seite6_imageinput").style.visibility = "hidden";
      $('#seite6_vorschau').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
$("#seite6_imageinput").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

function seite6_bildabb()
{
  document.getElementById("seite6_bb").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("seite6_imageinput").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function seite6_bildok()
{
  var seite6_crop_canvas = document.getElementById('seite6_canvas');
  var seite6_sleft = $('#seite6_vorschauaus').position().left;
  var seite6_top = $('#seite6_vorschauaus').position().top;

  seite6_crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage($('#seite6_vorschau')[0], seite6_sleft, seite6_top, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100); 

document.getElementById("seite6_profilbild1").src = seite6_crop_canvas.toDataURL();
  
    document.getElementById("seite6_bb").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("seite6_imageinput").style.visibility = "visible";

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>
<div id="seite6_bb" style="background: black; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 10; visibility: hidden;">
  
<img id="seite6_vorschau" src="#" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 80%;"/>
<div id="seite6_vorschauaus" style="position: absolute; height: 100px; width: 100px; background: white; opacity: 0.5; border: 1px solid black; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; height: 40px; background: white;">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 50%; height: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; color: #333333; font-family: RobotoMedium; line-height: 40px;" onclick="seite6_bildabb()">Abbrechen</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; width: 50%; height: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; border-left: 1px solid #656565; color: #333333; font-family: RobotoMedium; line-height: 40px;" onclick="seite6_bildok()">OK</div>
</div>
  
<canvas id="seite6_canvas" width="100" height="100" style="display:none;"></canvas>
</div>

<input id="seite6_imageinput" type="file" name="image" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 0px; background: lightgrey; z-index: 10;"/>
<img id="seite6_profilbild1" src="#" style="width: 150px; position: absolute; top: 30px;"/>

<script>
  var mcor3 = document.getElementById('seite6_vorschauaus');
  var mco3 = document.getElementById('seite6_vorschauaus',{ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
  var mc3 = new Hammer(mco3);
  mc3.on("pan", function(ev) {
    mcor3.style.left = ev.center.x+"px";
 mcor3.style.top = ev.center.y+"px";
  });
</script>
```

What did I do wrong?
Hope someone knows/find my mistake ;)

Comment: This doesn't look like android.

Comment: check http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/javascript-image-cropping-scripts/

Comment: Thanks for the Tip but i want to do it with my own code, so that i am having the full controle. Anyone can find the bug? 

Comment: here is implementation of cropping algorithm by using canvas https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas_image_processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake. I just scaled the image before cropping so the normail width, height were wrong.
Thanks for the Tips, hope I could help someone else
;)